# Can makefile be used to read input files?

Tags: c, makefile

I am working on a C project for class, where the linking and compilation is done through a makefile (thank God!).

But after that, i still have to type in all the input and output filenames (argv[] stuff) in the terminal like:

```
    ./proj c880.isc c880.vec c880.faults c880.out
```

My (silly) question is: can you somehow prepare your makefile such that i just have to type:

```
    ./proj 880
```

and everything gets taken care of?? i hate it when i have to run a whole buncha times with files with different numbers...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classically, you'd add a `test` target (probably as a `.PHONY` target):

```
.PHONY: test

test: proj
     ./proj c880.isc c880.vec c880.faults c880.out
```

You might also list the files like `c880.isc` as dependencies.

You might also parameterize it:

```
TEST = c880
PROG = proj
TEST_ARGS = ${TEST}.isc ${TEST}.vec ${TEST}.faults ${TEST}.out

.PHONY: test

test: ${PROG} ${TEST_ARGS}
    ./${PROG} ${TEST_ARGS}
```

Or you might need to treat `${TEST}.out separately from the others; it's a bit tricky to say, but the gist of the idea stands.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I quite understand what you're asking.  But you can definitely write a rule like this:

```
proj-%: proj
        $< c$*.isc c$*.vec c$*.faults c$*.out
```

then run `make proj-880` or `make proj-900` or whatever.